# Converting JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

The problem is that is not printing anything. I have list of surnames in aspx.cs, and I am trying to parse in JSON object so I can use them in aspx. I think the problem is in the script because when I `Response.Write('jsonString')` it prints in a correctly `JsonFormat`.

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

I have List of Surnames

```
public List<String> surname= new List<String>();
```

and a method that is making the list to `jsonString`

```
 public string getJson() {
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(surname);
            return jsonString;
        }
```

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
this is the script 
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/getJson",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#Label2").append(data + " ");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and web contorl

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Comment: So what's the problem??

Comment: it's not printing anything, edited :)

Comment: Does it fetch the value in `success`??

Comment: I am getting this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: have you put web method attribute on your code behind method ? have you referenced jquery library ?

Comment: I am using cdn for jquery, and when I make the method [web method] it must be static so I have to make list also static and it is printing this [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

have tried following line ?

in asp.net you have to get client id and than set your data

```
$('#<%=Label2.ClientID%>').html(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WebMethod should be like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> getJson()
{
      List<String> surname = YourFunctionForSurnames();
      return surname;
}
```

Your JavaScript

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/getJson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#Label2").append(data.d + " ");                    

            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest + '  ' +textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

I testing and working on my machine.

Comment: I am getting this error here :  var TheJson = TheSerializer.Serialize(surname);   ->  an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property

Comment: Updated (WebMethod) answer. Try now

Comment: Did it fix your problem ?

Comment: No, I am not creating the list in the particular function, I fill it from database .

Comment: You can use your WebMethod, as long as it returns List. Update you javaScript code as in answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need in js  to add JSON serialization before using the object, something like JSON.parse(jsonString);